# How to add members, in bulk, to a group with only userprincipalname?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a csv file in the following format

```
Userprincipalname
joe.blog@acme.com
winston.smart@acme.com
akshe.patel@acme.com
joseph.nkwame@acme
wonkyu.joon@acme.com
```

However when using the command `Add-AzureADGroupMember`, I can only add them by objectid, an user object id looks like this `1c00937a-80f1-48d8-88be-fcd3cXXXXa8e`

How can I use my csv file, translate it to object's id and then add these ids to the relevant group?

I tried the following to get the object id

```
$varname = Import-Csv .\avo-fr-sec.csv | %{Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $_.Userprincipalname} | SELECT ObjectId
```

But I'm stuck on how to add them to the group with the command `Add-AzureADGroupMember`, which can only accept object id as above.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this by iterating each object in a single foreach.
Store user objectid in a variable and if found add it to the group.

```
Import-Csv .\avo-fr-sec.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $ObjectId = (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $_.Userprincipalname).ObjectId
    If ($ObjectId) {
        Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "35d33b63-52cb-4802-bdac-986541XXX9c8" -RefObjectId $ObjectId
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I found my solution

Put everything in a variable

```
$varname = Import-Csv .\avo-fr-sec.csv | %{Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $_.Userprincipalname} | SELECT ObjectId
```

Once all the object id in the variable, here `varname`, use the variable with the command `Add-AzureADGroupMember`

```
$varname |%{Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "35d33b63-52cb-4802-bdac-986541XXX9c8" -RefObjectId $_.ObjectId}
```

As you can see `$_.ObjectId` can be used because in the previous command, everything was put in the variable with the header `ObjectId`

Answer (score 1):

I do mine like this. This way you don't need to look up and input the object ID evey time. Just edit the Azure AD group name $group. It will import that automatically and then check to see if the user by upn is already in it through the foreach line. Tell you in the console if they are already (if) and add them if they aren't (else)

```
#Connect to Azure AD 
Connect-AzureAD

#Import the list and save it to a variable
$list = Import-Csv 
"H:\Users_Reports\Users.csv"
#Insert the display name of the Azure group 
here
$group = "User Load Test"

#Retrieve the group name for use later in 
the script
$GroupObjectID = Get-AzureADGroup - 
SearchString $group | Select -Property 
ObjectID

#roll through the list to look up each user 
and add to the group. 
foreach ($y in $list){
$y2 = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId 
  $y.userPrincipalName | Select -Property 
 ObjectID
$members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId 
  $GroupObjectID.ObjectID -All $true

if ($y2.ObjectID -in $members.ObjectID) {
Write-Host $y.userPrincipalName'is already 
in the Group' -ForegroundColor Blue
}else{
    Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId 
$GroupObjectID.ObjectID -RefObjectId 
$y2.ObjectId -              
InformationAction SilentlyContinue
Write-Host $y.userPrincipalName'has been 
added to the Group' -ForegroundColor Green
}

}

#Disconnect Azure AD
Disconnect-AzureAD
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: The script seems malformed, could you please change to syntax into a runnable example?

Comment: Hey Dennis, 

What do you mean by malformed?